# new Date() only show the year or month and year

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

```
$scope.articles = [
    {
    link: "http://google.com",
    source: "Google",
    title: "hello",
    "date": new Date(2008, 4, 15)
    },
];

<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat = "article in articles | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:searchArticle ">
        <td>{{article.source}}</td>
        <td><a href="{{article.link}}" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">{{article.title}}</a></td>
        <td class="date-table-td">{{article.date | date:'longDate'}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody><!-- End table body -->
```

Hi, I currently have this. So the date shows as May 15, 2008. How do I show only the year or only the year+month?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: check [Date.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear)

Comment: Actually `new Date(2008, 4, 15)` should show up as May, not March.

Answer (score 3):

According to [the documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp), you can use `date.getFullYear()` to get the year in YYYY format and `date.getMonth()` to get the month.

An example:

```js
let list = document.getElementById('test');
let date = new Date(2008, 4, 15);


// year
let yearNode = document.createElement("li");
yearNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode(date.getFullYear()));

list.appendChild(yearNode)

// year + month

let yearMonthNode = document.createElement("li");
yearMonthNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode(date.getFullYear() + " " + date.getMonth()))

list.appendChild(yearMonthNode)
```

```html
<ul id="test">

</ul>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried `"date": new Date('2008, 4, 15').getFullYear()` but it is returning December 31, 1969

Comment: either remove the ' or add dashes between the items. `new Date('2018-4-15').getFullYear()` will work fine.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mention I have this `{{article.date | date:'longDate'}}` on the main page. When I removed `date:'longDate'` and added `"date": new Date('2008, 4, 15').getFullYear()` it worked so these two seem to be conflicting. However, now that I've removed the `longDate` format the dates are not formatted correctly anymore. Edited my original post.

Answer (score 0):

with `date.getMonth()` you need +1 to this 
`var month = date.getMonth() + 1`